# Change password in MySQL in App - Microsoft Azure

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

How can I change the password of user **azure** in MySQL in App?

*What I have tried so far*:
There are two configuration files named `MYSQLCONNSTR_localdb.txt` and `MYSQLCONNSTR_localdb.ini`. I have changed the default password there, but nothing happened. Also, if I change the password using PHPMyAdmin, then I cannot login again to PHPMyAdmin (for reasons unknown to me) using the new credentials.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Quoting [the doc](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/MySQL-in-app#can-i-customize-the-database-username-and-password-to-be-used):

> ***Can I customize the database, username and password to be used?***
>
> Yes. The connection string is stored at
>   `D:\home\data\mysql\MYSQLCONNSTR_localdb.txt`. The application (such
>   as wordpress) reads from this file for what database, username and
>   password to use. This also applies to what to backup and restore
>   provided by Azure WebApps. If you want to customize the database,
>   username and password, after you have created a new database, add new
>   username or update password, simply modify
>   `D:\home\data\mysql\MYSQLCONNSTR_localdb.ini`, **remove**
>   `D:\home\data\mysql\MYSQLCONNSTR_localdb.txt` and **restart** the WebApps.

Comment: I have done this but PhpMyAdmin does not work and present this [error](http://i.imgur.com/GtZMgTC.png).

Comment: Have you enabled **Always On** in Application Settings of Azure App Service?

Comment: It is turned off. But I cannot switch it on. It seems that this is due to the limitations of the Microsoft Imagine account that I have. Mysteriously, whatsoever, it worked after some hours. So I guess that, if **Always On** was enabled, the changes would take effect immediately.

Comment: dont forget the port. it was 55047 for me - meaning you put 127.0.0.1:55047 as the database server